# How to define collections in a common interface to fit EntityFrameworks auto generated collections?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm, entity-framework-6, portable-class-library

I'm creating a multi platform application (.NET 4.5/WPF, Windows Phone 8, SilverLight 5) using the MVVM pattern. My ViewModel project is a PCL (portable class library) shared/used by all platform specific Views. In my Windows application I want to access the database directly via Entity Framework 6.

I've two projects representing the data layer:
Data.Common: Includes entity/repository/unitofwork interfaces. They are used in my ViewModels.
Data.EF: Includes EntityFramework "stuff" (edmx file = auto generated DbContext and entity classes)

I will show my problem with my `IUser` interface:

```
// Data.Common.IUser
public interface IUser : IEntity
{
    // Primitives representing table columns.
    // They will be implemented fine by EF's auto generated classes.
    int ID { get; set;}
    string UserName { get; set; }

    // Collections representing table relations.
    // They are my problem because EF's generated classes don't fit to this.
    ICollection<IUserApplication> UserApplications { get; set; }
}
```

To implement my interface I created a partial class for each EF auto generated entity class in Data.EF project:

```
// Data.EF.User, my file
public partial class User : IUser
{
    // fields are implemented in other part
}

// Data.EF.User, file created by EntityFramework
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.UserApplications = new HashSet<UserApplication>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }             // fine, this implements IUser.ID
    public string UserName { get; set; }    // fine, this implements IUser.UserName

    // And here's the other part of my problem:
    // This collection is of type ICollection<UserApplication> but UserApplication is not known in my ViewModel, only IUserApplication.
    public virtual ICollection<UserApplication> UserApplications { get; set; }
}
```

How should the collections (like `ICollection<IUserApplication>`) representing the data table relations in my interfaces look like? It's not possible to simply cast a `Collection<IUserApplication>` to a `Collection<UserApplication>` so can this be achieved in any other way?